# WebApi action losing child collection from posted json

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

Suppose I post an object like this

```
{"Dto" : {
            "DtoId" : 1, 
            "DtoThing" : "Some value", 
            "DtoChildStuff" : [{"CsId" : 1, "ChildProperty" : "SomeThing"}]
           }}
```

to a WebApi action like this

```
[HttpPost]
public Response<MyDto> Post(DtoWrapper<MyDto> input)...
```

where the parameter is just some object with a property MyDto of type MyDto, and MyDto is like this

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int DtoId {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string DtoThing {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public List<ChildStuffDto> DtoChildStuff {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ChildStuffDto
{   
    [DataMember]
    public int CsId {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string ChildProperty {get;set;}
}
```

and (by the way) the DtoWrapper is just

```
public class DtoWrapper<T>
{
   public T Dto {get;set;}
   // So that I can add some other info that I need //
}
```

Why can't the action see any child objects. If I change the type on the parameter to object, I can see the child object being posted in, but it doesn't get deserialised. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the code for your wrapper class

Comment: In that case, it should work. I don't see anything wrong here. Have you checked the ModelState property for deserialization errors?

Comment: You posted code for `MyDto` but that's not the type you expect in the method. The expected type is `SomeWrapperForMyDto`. Can you post the code for that instead and check that this object does have the collection as well ?

Comment: Hopefully the latest edit covers any doubts about what the outer object is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my answer, but I'd love to know if there's a way I can get it to happen without adding this line of code to my action.

```
    public Response<MyDto> Post(object input)
    {

        dynamic myWrapperObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeWrapperForMyDto>
                             (input.ToString());
        ...
```

If that's how it has to be then fair play, but it seems a shame. Thanks for any posts :)

Comment: You really shouldn't have to do that... How is this even working if input isn't being deserialized correctly???

Comment: Hang on. Sorry, the type on the post method is now object my bad. I know I shouldn't have to but it is the only thing that has worked so far.

Comment: By the way, if you just turn "object" into "dynamic" it should work fine. But what you had above, deserializing into a type should work too. Can you try checking if the ModelState on your controller is valid when you bind your wrapper object?

Comment: Model state is valid, and it was before when I couldn't get the child objects. I'm happy with it now. Thanks for your help at this early hour :)